# OOP ajax to avoid code duplication

Tags: javascript, php, oop, jquery

```
            var ajaxquery= $.ajax({
                url: "backend.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {data:data},
                dataType: "text"
            });
```

for example I have multiple data needed to be send upon users' interaction. for above code, example, it's for the data insertion into the backend. But I also have other operation like update and delete, and many other fields. I plan to OOP the above code to reuse it, but it unlike function. I was expecting something like this:

```
var insert = new ajaxquery(url,data,callback);
var delete = new ajaxquery(url,data,callback);
```

possible?

Comment: You could put it in a function with as parameter all the data variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do achieve that using closures:

```
function ajaxQuery(url,callback) {
  return function(data) {
     return $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: {data:data},
                dataType: "text",
                success: callback
            });
    }
  }
}
var insert = ajaxquery(url,callback);
insert("somedata");
insert("another data");
var deleteFn = ajaxquery(url2,callback2);
deleteFn("field");
deleteFn("another Field");
```

Comment: there are 2 param in here, var insert = ajaxquery(url,callback);
but u pass one instead of two here : insert("somedata"); why??

Comment: because ajaxQuery will return a function, this function is the one that get assigned to insert variable and it accept only one argument. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: I see. one more question. Why you didn't use new keyword? you're not using any object in this case?